# How to prevent cups from timing out jobs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, printer, cups

I upgraded from Ubuntu Precise (12.04) to Trusty (14.04) and now it seems CUPS times out jobs and automatically deletes them after exactly 3 hours.

However I usually do not have the printer running all the time, but just start it up from time to time to print any pending print job, so I would like to have no timeout at all for print jobs that cannot be printed immediately.

How do I configure CUPS to do that? I reviewed all the configuration options, but could not find any that seem to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself at https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.0/man-cupsd.conf.html after searching some more:

```
MaxJobTime seconds
    Specifies the maximum time a job may take to print before it is canceled. 
    Set to "0" to disable cancellation of "stuck" jobs. The default is "10800" (3 hours).
```